# Is there anyway to dynamically enable / disable the highlighting in Vim?

Tags: vim, macvim

Ok so basically the way Vim highlights searches displeases me. Basically you do a search, then you have to type /asdf or have a shortcut like this in your vimrc:

```
nn <silent> <leader><space> :noh<CR>
```

Which is what I have. But it's still too much mental work. Basically, when I do a search, I want highlighting to enable (like it does now) but if I do anything other than cycle through the searches (with n/N) then I want highlighting to turn off. That's basically my workflow, so I'm wondering if I can automate it. Also if I search, do something other than n/N (which should turn highlighting off) and then press n/N again, it should re-enable.

Any ideas?

Comment: Compromise: Make your mapping even simpler, e.g. I find `:nnoremap <silent> <BS> :nohls<CR>` quite intuitive (one keystroke!).

Comment: @glts: judging by the identical answer below with one downvote, that's not what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's difficult. One idea is

```
:autocmd CursorHold * call feedkeys(":noh\<CR>")
```

(One needs to use `feedkeys()` because `:nohlsearch` is ineffective in functions and autocmds.) This clears the highlighting whenever you pause the cursor for some seconds. You can add other triggers like `InsertEnter` or `CursorHoldI`.

What does not work is `CursorMoved`, because the searches and `n` / `N` jump as well. You would need to overload those commands, store the cursor position after the jump, and modify the autocmd to only clear the highlighting when the position is different.

What I do: I have <kbd>Enter</kbd> mapped to `:nohlsearch`; it's quick and easy to reach.

Answer (score 0):

you can turn it on or off with:

`:set hls`

or

`:set nohls`

I have <kbd>F7</kbd> mapped to `set hls!`:

```
noremap <F7>    :set hls!<CR>
```